# How to reflect an image on a IcosahedronGeometry in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to make IcosahedronGeometry in three.js and reflect an image on the front side of the geometry.

I already made a IcosahedronGeometry and made it rotate on it's axis.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

// RENDERER
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});

// RENDERER - SIZE OF CANVAS
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor('#ffffff');
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// RESPONSIVE RENDERING
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});

var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  shininess: 100,
  color: 0xffffff,
  specular: 0xffffff
});
const cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(75, 1000, 512);
scene.add(cubeCamera);
// GEOMETRY
var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(2, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0x98bbbd,
  side: THREE.FrontSides,
  roughness: 1,
  metalness: 0.5,
  envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget
});

material.roughness = 0;
material.metalness = 1;
material.flatShading = true;
material.envMap = cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture;
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);

console.log(sphere.position);
console.log(cubeCamera.position);
cubeCamera.position.copy(sphere.position);
cubeCamera.update(renderer, scene);

// FLOOR
var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/woman.png');
// floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
// floorTexture.repeat.set(1000, 1000);
var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: floorTexture,
  side: THREE.BackSide
});
var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5, 5, 1, 1);
var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
floor.position.y = 0;
floor.position.x = 0;
floor.position.z = 3;
scene.add(floor);

cubeCamera.lookAt(floor);
// CONTROLS
var orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.Mesh);
camera.position.z = 5;

// LIGHTS
var topLeftLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 1);
topLeftLight.position.set(-50, 50, -25);
scene.add(topLeftLight);

var topRightLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 10);
topRightLight.position.set(50, 150, -25);
scene.add(topRightLight);

var lightBottomRight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
lightBottomRight.position.set(40, -50, 25);
scene.add(lightBottomRight);

var lightBottomLeft = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
lightBottomLeft.position.set(-40, -50, 25);
scene.add(lightBottomLeft);

var lightTopRight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
lightTopRight.position.set(40, 50, 25);
scene.add(lightTopRight);

var lightTopLeft = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
lightTopLeft.position.set(-40, 50, 25);
scene.add(lightTopLeft);

var backLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
backLight.position.set(0, 0, -25);
scene.add(backLight);

var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 2); // soft white light
scene.add(light);

// update function
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  sphere.rotation.x += 0.005;
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.005;

  sphere.visible = false;
  cubeCamera.update(renderer, scene);
  sphere.visible = true;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
render();
```

I would like to see a rotating IcosahedronGeometry which reflects an image on the front side. I tried adding a cube camera and pointing it at the PlaneGeometry with an image texture but nothing is reflecting.
I would like to simulate something like this, but it doesn't have to be exactly the same.

The desired result.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 issues.

1. you have to call `cubeCamera.update` **before** you access `cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture`
2. The parameters to `CubeCamera` are `new CubeCamera(near, far, size)`.

   The code had `new CubeCamera(75, 1000, 512)` which means only things 75 to 1000 units away from the camera would be visible. The image plane you had is 3 units away so would not be visible.
3. You don't call `lookAt` with the `CubeCamera` as it's always looking in all directions.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

// RENDERER
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});

// RENDERER - SIZE OF CANVAS
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor('#ffffff');
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// RESPONSIVE RENDERING
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});

var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  shininess: 100,
  color: 0xffffff,
  specular: 0xffffff
});
const cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(0.001, 10, 512);
scene.add(cubeCamera);
// GEOMETRY
var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(2, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0x98bbbd,
  side: THREE.FrontSide,
  roughness: 1,
  metalness: 0.5,
});
cubeCamera.update(renderer, scene);

material.roughness = 0;
material.metalness = 1;
material.flatShading = true;
material.envMap = cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture;
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);

// FLOOR
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var floorTexture = loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/UKBsvV0.jpg');
var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: floorTexture,
  side: THREE.BackSide
});
var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5, 5, 1, 1);
var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
floor.position.y = 0;
floor.position.x = 0;
floor.position.z = 3;
scene.add(floor);

// CONTROLS
var orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.Mesh);
camera.position.z = 5;

// LIGHTS
var topLeftLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 1);
topLeftLight.position.set(-50, 50, -25);
scene.add(topLeftLight);

var topRightLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 10);
topRightLight.position.set(50, 150, -25);
scene.add(topRightLight);

var lightBottomRight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
lightBottomRight.position.set(40, -50, 25);
scene.add(lightBottomRight);

var lightBottomLeft = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
lightBottomLeft.position.set(-40, -50, 25);
scene.add(lightBottomLeft);

var lightTopRight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
lightTopRight.position.set(40, 50, 25);
scene.add(lightTopRight);

var lightTopLeft = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
lightTopLeft.position.set(-40, 50, 25);
scene.add(lightTopLeft);

var backLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
backLight.position.set(0, 0, -25);
scene.add(backLight);

var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 2); // soft white light
scene.add(light);

// update function
function render() {
  sphere.rotation.x += 0.005;
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.005;

  sphere.visible = false;
  cubeCamera.update(renderer, scene);
  sphere.visible = true;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```